# Python sep= ", " But Only Want It 2nd Time Onwards

Tags: python

So i am making a Basic text game as I progress learning python.
As i offer choices i am trying to print choices from a list and i have these lines of code:

`hubchoices = ["fight","shop","upgrade stats"]`

```
print("You Can,"hubchoices[0].capitalize(),,hubchoices[1].capitalize(),hubchoices[2].capitalize(), sep= ", ")
```

The output i receive is this:

```
You Can, Fight, Shop, Upgrade stats
```

is there a way to have the sep= ", " work only after the first comma to get something more like this:

```
You Can Fight, Shop, Upgrade stats
```

(and also a way to capitalize the first letter of every word with .capitalize())

Comment: Your actual received output has the 0th element from `hubchoices` even though it shouldn't display according to the code. Can you correct the discrepancy?

Comment: Oh, and the short answer to your question is "no." The `print()` function's `sep` is applied to all arguments, so you have to use some kind of string operation to get the output you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print("You Can %s" % ','.join([c.capitalize() for c in hubchoices]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try string formatting.

```
hubchoices = ["fight","shop","upgrade stats"]
'You can: {}, {}'.format(*map(str.capitalize, hubchoices[1:]))
```

Result:

```
'You can: Shop, Upgrade stats'
```

Comment: I think he meant he only wants a comma between the first and second choices, so the `[1:]` is not needed.

Comment: @Reut, 1. The OP's code only includes the last two elements of the `list`, but the output shows all three elements. 2. The output has a comma between each `list` element. 3. The difference between the produced output and the desired output is the comma after `can`. Regardless, the title's question - making the `print()` function's `sep` argument apply only to certain elements - is interesting but not possible. It has to be done with string operations.